# Esfera de Bloch para más de un qubit

Tags: matemáticas, computación-cuántica

Si represento mi estado en la esfera de Bloch como

```
|ψ⟩=a|u⟩+b|v⟩
```

donde

```
|ψ⟩=cos(θ2)|u⟩+eiϕsin(θ2)|v⟩,
```

puedo ver la posición de mi qubit dentro de la esfera.

Ahora, si tengo 2 qubits o más y quiero comprobar si están sobre el plano xy. Imaginemos que tengo el estado para dos qubits

```
|ψ⟩=[0.5;0.5i;0.5i;-0.5],
```

¿Cómo puedo ver dónde están los qubits dentro de la esfera?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se supone que para añadir mas qbits debería se lo mismo que para 1? (un estoy procesando que es lo que significa cada cosa jeje) puedes intentar usar estos simuladores [link 1](http://ttphan.github.io/Quantum-Bloch-Sphere-Simulator/), [Link 2](http://eecs.ceas.uc.edu/~mcahay/blochsphere/)

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no está relacionada con ningún lenguaje de programación.